# How to call a script component from a GameObject that is child to another GameObject, but from other GameObject?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my unity project, I have a GameObject called "Spawn_manager", that has another Child GameObject called "Enemy_Container". The script of Spawn_Manager makes "Enemy" prefabs instantiate inside the "Enemy_Container". I am trying to acess the "Enemy" script(also named Enemy) from another script.

Anyone knows how I can get it?

I tried writing this:

```
private Enemy _enemy;

private void Start()
{
    _enemy = GameObject.Find("Enemy").GetComponent<Enemy>();
}
```

But obviously it is not working, but I can't get it to work. Basically, I wanna the script, and the path would be Spawn_Manager>Enemy_Container>Enemy.

Comment: Have you tried [FindObjectOfType](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectOfType.html) ? Or you can Find the parent transform and perform Find operation from that transform so it will look at it's children.

Comment: @ÇağatayIŞIK but what type wold I insert? I also don't know how to use find operation from the transform

Comment: You want a script? You mean, an assigned component of the type "Enemy"? On which object is it exactly? Any child of your enemy container or a specific one? Also, "unityscript" is deprecated, the tag shouldn't be used anymore.

Comment: [`GetComponentInChildren`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponentInChildren.html) ...?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the Enemy easily accessible you can add all spawned `Enemy` to static list. Like this:

```
    public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public static List<Enemy> AllEnemy { get; private set; } = new List<Enemy>();

        private void Awake()
        {
            AllEnemy.Add(this);
        }

        private void OnDestroy()
        {
            AllEnemy.Remove(this);
        }
    }
```

Using `Find` is demanding and not a reliable operation. If you will have any other GameObjects with name Enemy it will found them instead of desired one.
in this case i think that problem is that after instantiation prefab new GameObject have name in format `$"{prefab.name}(Clone)`".

Comment: I would rather use a `private static readonly List<Enemy> _instances = new();` and then only expose it as `public IReadOnlyList<Enemy> Instances => _instances;` .. otherwise any other class could simply add, remove items and clear the list ;)

Comment: Yes, but why overcomplicate things for junior person?
Other solution is to return new copy of list/array each time you get it.

Comment: Returning a copy would be bad memory and performance wise .. this is not overcomplicating ^^ why throw a mediocre solution at a junior when you can provide a solid one?

Comment: Because it harder to understand, but yes it is good to mention how you can improve it.